# How do you connect a QProgressBar with a function?

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt4, qprogressbar

I'm working on a program and I want to connect a QProgressBar with a function.  While the function is in progress, the QProgressBar should count until the function is done.  Then the  QProgressBar should be done too.

Comment: You should maybe accept more answers for questions you've asked in the past.  You've only accepted answers on 9% of the questions you've asked.  This will not inspire others to help you.

Comment: Read the QProgressBar documentation, it's quite clear on how to use it. https://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qprogressbar.html#details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample will give you a simple idea of seeing the progress. By no way this is efficient or elegant. Its a just a working solution i rigged up.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, sys

from time import sleep

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

app = QApplication( sys.argv )

def copyFile() :
    cpBtn.setDisabled( True )
    for i in range( 0, 100 ) :
        # File Copy Code
        # sleep( 0.1 ) is instead of the file copy code
        sleep( 0.1 )
        pb.setValue( i + 1 )
        qApp.processEvents()

    cpBtn.setEnabled( True )
    pb.reset()

fcpDlg = QDialog()

cpBtn = QPushButton( fcpDlg )
cpBtn.setText( "&Copy" )
cpBtn.clicked.connect( copyFile )
cpBtn.setFixedWidth( 72 )

pb = QProgressBar()
pb.setMinimumWidth( 300 )
pb.setRange( 0, 100 )

lyt = QVBoxLayout( fcpDlg )
lyt.addWidget( pb )
lyt.addWidget( cpBtn )

fcpDlg.setLayout( lyt )

fcpDlg.show()

sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```